# Redshift : returning temp table results from stored procedure when using Security Definer

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a stored procedure that creates & populates a temp table as per AWS docs :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html

However the stored procedure also executes with SECURITY DEFINER.

Whilst the caller has EXECUTE permissions to call the procedure, it is getting denied when trying to SELECT form the resultant temp table.

I am hoping that there is a tried & tested solution for this , or am I supposed to try and identify the caller's identity and make a grant on the fly ?

Here's steps to recreate :

```
-- as Super User
CREATE TABLE test.test_tbl(a int);
INSERT INTO test.test_tbl(a) values(1);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "test".test_sp(INOUT tmp_name character varying(256))
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'drop table if exists ' || tmp_name;
  EXECUTE 'create temp table ' || tmp_name || ' as select * from test.test_tbl;';
END;
$$

-- test user
create user test123 password disable;
grant usage on schema test to test123;
grant execute on procedure "test".test_sp(varchar) to test123;

-- test call 
set session authorization test123;
call "test".test_sp('myresult');
select * from myresult;
-- Result : ERROR: permission denied for relation myresult
```

Comment: You need to create a [mre] including creation of all necessary objects, and which users create / own / execute what.

Comment: Done , thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

I’m away from my database right now but I think you need to grant drop privileges or not start with the table being created by superuser.